# Webpage using React and one <div> id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am still learning React and finding it a little harder to learn than I expected, I am also still learning web development.

If we have only one view in our app, and we have only one div like so:

```
<body>

<div id="react-app"></div>

</body>
```

does that mean that our all our React components will be traced up to one React parent component?

Does this mean that when we render the page, we only call render() on the top level parent component and then React will take care of the rest? How can we render child elements asynchronously, if we are waiting for data?

Answer (score 2):

> does that mean that our all our React components will be traced up to one React parent component?

Yes exactly. Your React application will be a tree that has one single, top-level parent node. When that parent node gets rendered, React will recursively call `render` for any child components that you've declared in its parent's `render` call.

> How can we render child elements asynchronously, if we are waiting for data?

The whole idea of React is to declare what your UI will look like under any circumstances, such as initial state, waiting for data state, data returned state and data error state.

Consider the following example:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    // set initial state
    this.state = { images: [], error: null }

    getDataFromServer('url').then(

      // success callback
      data => this.setState({ images: data.images }),

      // error callback
      data => this.setState({ error: data.error })
    )

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { // only render ImageGallery component if async call returns with data
          this.state.images.length > 0 && 
          <ImageGallery images={ this.state.images } />
        }
        { this.state.images.length === 0 &&
          <div>Loading / No images returned.</div>
        }
        { this.state.error &&
          <ErrorPopup error={ this.state.error } />
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Child components are dependent on the state of the parent component, `<App />`, which gets its state in any number of ways, including an ajax call in the constructor (or `componentWillMount, componentDidMount`, etc)